# Style.css link is showing the old copy of style.css

Tags: css

I have made some changes in style.css and uploaded it online. However it is not showing me required results. i.e it is still taking the old style.css codes.

I am able to view changes offline but when i give it full href link it is not showing me necessary results.

Help!!

Comment: I tried all the suggested methods, but the problem persists. I have my style.css with 24kb , when I upload it I can see only some part of style.css code is displayed online. Please check the given link http://www.redlook.in/css/style.css . Becaouse of that the website is also not resolving correctly!! :(

Answer (score 1):

It seems like there is a cached version that you are viewing. Try clearing the cache in your browser and reloading the page. If that doesn't work then most likely the web hosting you are using is caching the stylesheet.

Answer (score 1):

Open website with another browser. If css is still old, I can tell you that you have definitively not update the css file.

Another thing to do is to clear cache of your browser. It is possible you are viewing cache. Which browser are you using? Check how to clear cache.

Comment: I cleared cache and checked but same problem. I have added expiry header for css in .htaccess file. Is it because of that which is causing problem to me regarding style.css?

Comment: If you want an answer, ... remove it and tell us what happens ^_^. I think ... "maybe".

Comment: I tried all the suggested methods. Even made changes to .htaccess file by removing the caching codes but the problem was not solved. Finally I introduces new stylesheet inplace of style.css and called that one. Now it is working fine...  There is some problem with style.css file and I still don't know what was that...!

Comment: Ok, just delete files. If you still see them in your browser we have a problem.

Comment: I tried getting solution for my query about style.css in many forum and tried all the things suggested by them but i didn't get the desired solution. So finally I replaced the css and now it is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably using a cached version of your CSS. If this happens in other browsers too, then problem is in somewhere else.

You can fix this by:

- clearing the cache (see [refreshyourcache.com](http://www.refreshyourcache.com)) or
- going to your CSS path by browser (e.g. *mysite.com/css/file.css*) and refreshing the page.
- doing *force refresh* (usually `Ctrl+F5` or `F5`)